# CSV parsing nested quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-commons

I try to parse a fairly complex CSV with apache sparks CSV reader which internally relies on the apache commons library (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

I tried different combination of 
`quoteMode` and `escape` but could not get it to work e.g. prevent the exceptions. Do you have any hints which parameters would support such a nested Structure?

```
 ERROR CsvRelation$: Exception while parsing line: "Gabriella's Song" From The Motion Picture "The Mission"; 
java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
```

I know that `sed` could be used to pre-process the data. However, it would be great if was integrated into Spark  e.g. if no further pre-processing was needed. I did not find the possibility to specify a regex or so.

The CSV file looks like:

```
"Gabriella's Song" From The Motion Picture "The Mission";
```

Comment: Have your tired to use alternative parsing engine?

Comment: So far not because I do not know which engine would support it. Do you know such an engine?

Comment: You don't have much choice here :) `spark-csv` supports only `univocity` as an alternative.

Comment: But `spark-csv`supports `parserLib` - shouldn't it be possible to integrate other CSV libraries there?

Comment: Probably, although I am not sure if it is available out of the box. What you've shown is a complete line? If not could you put it in some context.

Comment: This is the field which generates the error. But right now I have a single CSV file containing only this single line.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/readers/readers.scala they use univocity internally ?

Comment: For this input setting quote option to something else than `"` should be enough. Question is if it works for you in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106496/discussion-between-zero323-and-geoheil).

Comment: Would you like to write an answer as your last suggestion is correct, even though it only solves this particular case.

Comment: Regarding the "bigger data" this is the next issue: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/295

some more special fields like

```
&amp;
Or "Eccoli; attenti ben (Don Pasquale)"
```

Cause these Problems. We will write our own CSV Pre-Processor for Apache Camel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it worked very well for me -

```
HDFS file -
spark.read.option("WholeFile", true).option("delimiter", ",").csv(s"hdfs://{my-hdfs-file-path}")

Non-HDFS file -
spark.read.option("WholeFile", true).option("delimiter", ",").csv(my-hdfs-file-path)
```

Above approach works for any delimited file, just change the delimiter value.

You can also use Regex but that will very in-efficient for large files.

Hope this is helpful.